# Should I use an ORM to model a large tree structure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

We are developing a Video on demand system where users can upload videos. We want to create a tree structure of the archive of videos where the user can create folders of artists/albums etc and store the videos under the correct folders. Like all tree structures, the user will be able to move videos between folders, delete sub trees, copy videos and move sub trees and children.

The tree could have 10s of 1000s of videos and folders.

My question is would an ORM be suitable for a tree like structure of this size?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your tree structure in the database is going to be some table like:

FolderId | ParentFolderId | FolderName

Why not?

The question is not should you use ORM or not, the question is what problem do you have that ORM is a right tool to solve.

Comment: Currently we have to decide on how we persist the data. Learning an ORM maybe difficult with the time scale of the project. With that table structure, I suppose I could just hand craft the SQL?

Comment: "With that table structure, I suppose I could just hand craft the SQL?" Exactly what I think, stay away from ORM unless you have a complicated/large data structure.

Comment: First you need to define your data and busines logic. THEN you should think how to persist it and how to access it easily. I cannot answer your question of "just hand craft the SQL" because I don't know your usecases. For example, if I need to load the whole tree in one go, why don't I just join this table to the permissions table in order to get ALL the folders that belong to a user? Or if I need to load next level only when user navigates there, why can't I just ask for "Where(x=>x.ParentId=selectedId)"? I can perfectly use ANY ORM for this purpose. Or NO ORM as it is simple. Or write an SP.